# Why does Xcode 4 compile test target when I build non-test target

Tags: iphone, build, xcode4, target

Xcode 4 project contains two targets: "**normal**" application target and "**test**" target. When I select "normal" target scheme and do build, I get compile errors and warnings from both targets.

"Normal" application target dependency is empty, test target is depending on normal app.

What do I need to do to **build only normal application**, when I have selected normal app scheme? Theory, politics and best practices be what they are - I want to control what I build!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose Product > Build For > Build For Running to build the application target only.

Comment: My question was a wrong one, but you answered it correctly. Thus approved. Additionally you helped me to get to right direction and solve the real problem, which I didn't recognize: how to clear old build results. Now everything is perfect!